Minimal bash like line editing is supported
I got this message after turning on the computer. I tried various "solutions" from the net. But nothing fixed the issue. I ran boot recovery via USB and got below code.
boot-repair-4ppa2074                                              [20240813_0359]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================




Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

No OS to fix.
No OS to fix.
Please backup your data before this operation.
No OS to fix.
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.





============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/neon/grubx64.efi /efi/neon/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/neon/shimx64.efi /efi/neon/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sda2: can't read superblock on /dev/sda2.

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/neon/grubx64.efi /efi/neon/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/neon/shimx64.efi /efi/neon/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg

sdc3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   KDE neon 6.0 (22.04) on sda2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] from NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F64a(5.17) from American Megatrends International, LLC.
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).


a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sda1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   sda1/neon/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/neon/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/neon/shimx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 7425488E-862F-6C4A-893F-AF41C2DCD5A7
          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1        4096     618495     614400   300M EFI System
sda2      618496 1917663240 1917044745 914.1G Linux filesystem
sda3  1917663241 1953520064   35856824  17.1G Linux swap
Disk sdb: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x14eb2669
     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *          0  5138431  5138432  2.5G  0 Empty
sdb2           572     9067     8496  4.1M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdb3       5140480 61439999 56299520 26.8G 83 Linux
Disk sdc: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: EAC9A507-860D-C148-B073-3B90C31C69B2
         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdc1       4096    618495    614400   300M EFI System
sdc2     618496 958313126 957694631 456.7G Linux filesystem
sdc3  958313127 976768064  18454938   8.8G Linux swap

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA CT1000MX500SSD1:;
1:2097kB:317MB:315MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:317MB:982GB:982GB:ext4:root:;
3:982GB:1000GB:18.4GB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
sdb:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
2:293kB:4643kB:4350kB:::esp;
3:2632MB:31.5GB:28.8GB:ext4::;
sdc:500GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA CT500MX500SSD1:;
1:2097kB:317MB:315MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:317MB:491GB:490GB::root:;
3:491GB:500GB:9449MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sdb: 4.43MiB:2510MiB:2506MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                              
├─sda1 vfat     9BEB-B04B                            9e27c225-20af-c340-959a-2a756a3f1e7a                        
├─sda2 ext4     547a1e8f-54ee-481b-abf3-1e5d7d6984a8 2f494d71-28b8-7e49-a286-068bb231bb4f                        root
└─sda3 swap     8520a3d2-abea-4fd0-8e24-dee317ff7fd4 a825078a-596d-5d42-95e0-0fed348c91bb swap                   
sdb    iso9660  2023-12-23-05-05-55-00                                                    Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2023-12-23-05-05-55-00               14eb2669-01                          Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sdb2 vfat     8D6C-A9F8                            14eb2669-02                          ESP                    
└─sdb3 ext4     1f66b8b0-c6d6-431e-8389-111c5327d8e6 14eb2669-03                          writable               
sdc                                                                                                              
├─sdc1 vfat     6D28-1720                            a8732f44-b32f-2c4e-92f9-62461d272455                        
├─sdc2 iso9660  2023-09-26-18-20-20-00               feaf8302-1bd6-0e4e-9449-fc7b8daff543 elementary OS          root
└─sdc3 swap     9d3bea79-c9d7-4907-b5f0-ddfcc846d2d7 59c6ddc7-045f-044f-891c-a76d4c72dabd swap                   

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                             Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                                   293.3M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sdb1                                                        0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1                                                   vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb1                                                   iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

====================== sda1/efi/neon/grub.cfg (filtered) =======================

search.fs_uuid 547a1e8f-54ee-481b-abf3-1e5d7d6984a8 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 547a1e8f-54ee-481b-abf3-1e5d7d6984a8 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sdc1/efi/neon/grub.cfg (filtered) =======================

search.fs_uuid d744ee2b-7557-4909-bce8-72818042c125 root hd1,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

===================== sdc1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid d744ee2b-7557-4909-bce8-72818042c125 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sdc2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or install elementary OS
Try or install elementary OS (Safe graphics)

==================== sdc2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
            ?? = ??             boot/vmlinuz                                   1
            ?? = ??             boot/initrd.img                                1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sdc2

Unknown BootLoader on sdb

sprunge.us ko ()


Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  Your paste shows details relating to Linux Mint, KDE Neon, Elementary .. but no specifics that relate to an on-topic system were detected
